# How to install "not installable" dependancies?

Tags: ubuntu, package, apt, codelite, ubuntu-17.10

I'm trying to install Codelite on Ubuntu Artful (17.10). I've seen this problem is very common online but I haven't found a fix. Basically when I run `sudo apt-get install codelite wxcrafter` I get these unmet dependancies

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 codelite : Depends: libclang1-3.6 (>= 3.2) but it is not installable
            Depends: libhunspell-1.3-0 (>= 1.3.3) but it is not installable
            Depends: liblldb-3.6 but it is not installable
            Recommends: lldb (>= 3.4) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Now I've tried to manually install Artful versions of the dependancies (such as https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/libclang1-3.9) but the error remains there. I'm kind of a noob on these sort of things. Is there anyway to like manually install a dependancy? (from like a downloaded file?) Or is there any sort of fix to this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This might be more likely to get a good answer on [ubuntu.se]

Comment: My issue ended up being that I had a pending ubuntu release waiting to be upgraded. running `do-release-upgrade` did the trick and all became as was intended.

Answer (score 4):

By running the command `sudo apt-get -f install` it fix my problem. **-f** mean --fix-broken.

Answer (score 2):

try the following

```
sudo apt install aptitude    
sudo aptitude install codelite wxcrafter
```